# Django setUpTestData() does not work with inheritance?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

```
class MotherTestCase(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.my_value = "foo"

class ChildTestCase(MotherTestCase):

    def test_basic(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.my_value, "foo")
```

When running this test, I get a `AttributeError: 'ChildTestCase' object has no attribute 'my_value'`

How can you explain this? I thougt I need to call `super()` but the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData) doesn't say so

I saw a [related issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/pull/266) on Github but it's 1 year old and seems to be fixed.

Note: I'm using Python 3.5.2 and Django 1.9.10

Comment: Oops, forget to mention that sorry. I'm using Python 3.5.2 and Django 1.9.10

Comment: Are you using pytest and pytest-django? The issue you linked to is for pytest-django.

Comment: Thanks! You solved my problem asking this question :) I was importing TestCase from `unittest.case`instead of `django.test`. PyCharm auto-import... :p

Comment: Great, glad you figured out the problem :)

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of confusing, but there are 2 different `TestCase` classes. There is the `unittest.TestCase` and there's the Django test case class `django.test.TestCase`. In order for this to work, you have to be importing from `django.test`, not unitttest.